# Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined on onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, function, referenceerror

I am new to coding but am having a really hard time trying to figure out why I am getting referenceError in Chrome on the "Add new task" button with nothing happening.

This is my function which creates the view and i am trying to have a onclick function which brings up a lightbox with fields.

The Add New Task button is located towards bottom of the code snippet

Appreciate the help!

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function action_form(id) {
          $("#dialog_form").remove();
          $("#tasks-form").append('
        <div id="dialog_form"></div>');
          $("#dialog_form").attr("title", (id !== undefined ? "Edit task" : "Create new task"));
          $("#dialog_form").html('
        <div>' + '
    </script>

    <div class="blocks">
      <h1>Tasks for your MultiScraper</h1>
      <div class="text-block">
        <input type="button" value=" + Add new task" class="btn btn-blue" onclick="action_form();" id="tasks_add_button" style="float: right;margin: 10px 30px 10px 0;" />
        <input type="button" value="Products grabbed" class="btn btn-grey" onclick="" id="tasks_grabbed_product_button" style="float: left;margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;" />
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div id="tasks-form" class="ms_form" style="padding: 10px;width: 1240px;padding-bottom: 0;">
          <div id="form-content">

            <table class="list" id="parser_instruction_table">
              <thead>
                <tr id="instruction_table_header">
                  <td colspan="10">You have not yet made ​​any task for your MSPRO. Please, create the first one</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
```

Comment: Please only post the **well formatted relevant code**, no one wants to debug a few hundred lines of spaghetti for you.

Comment: Sorry, I've cleaned up the code to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
function action_form(id) {
    $("#dialog_form").remove();
    $("#tasks-form").append('
                           <div id="dialog_form"></div>');
    $("#dialog_form").attr("title", (id !== undefined ? "Edit task" : "Create new task"));
    $("#dialog_form").html('
                          <div>' + '
```

Leaving a line break while you write a string, like you do in

```
$("#tasks-form").append('
                       <div id="dialog_form"></div>');
```

and

```
$("#dialog_form").html('
                      <div>' + '
```

will result in an error.

Do

```
$("#tasks-form").append('<div id="dialog_form"></div>');
```

or, if you **have** to break to a new line

```
$("#tasks-form").append('' +
                       '<div id="dialog_form"></div>');
```

Also, there is something wrong with

```
$("#dialog_form").html('<div>' + '
```

It looks like you have forgotten to close the parentheses and the brackets of your function